# Ошибка при использовании кастомного редактора настроек

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно создать кастомный редактор настроек моего приложения. Я создал класс `CustomEditTextPreference`, который является потомком класса `EditTextPreference`. Вот его код:

```
package com.dialog.main;

import com.dialog.main.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class CustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference
{
//  private EditText mEditText;
//  private String mText;

    public CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomEditTextPreference(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view)
    {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        getEditText().setTextSize(getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size));
    }
}
```

Затем я добавил этот кастомный редактор в файл разметки экрана настроек. Вот что получилось:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:layout="@layout/preference_category"
        android:title="@string/PreferenceTerminalActivity_titleSaleRep">

        <com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference
            android:key="pref_termName" 
            android:title="@string/PreferenceTerminalActivity_titleSaleRepName" 
            android:summary="@string/PreferenceTerminalActivity_titleSaleRepName"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/PreferenceTerminalActivity_titleSaleRepName"
            android:defaultValue="">
        </com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference>

    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

При создании активности для управления настройками:

```
package com.dialog.main;

import com.dialog.utils.Messenger;
import com.dialog.main.R;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class PreferenceTerminalActivity extends PreferenceActivity  implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    private DialogApp mApp;

    private String prevTerm = "";

    public static final String KEY_PREF_TERMNAME = "pref_termName";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_terminal);

        mApp = (DialogApp) this.getApplication();

        Preference prefTermName = findPreference(KEY_PREF_TERMNAME);
        prevTerm  = ((EditTextPreference) prefTermName).getText();
        prefTermName.setSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getString(KEY_PREF_TERMNAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) 
    {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);

        if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_TERMNAME))
        {
            if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) 
            {
                pref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
            }

            String tmp = ((EditTextPreference) pref).getText();

            if(!prevTerm.equalsIgnoreCase(tmp))
            {
                prevTerm = tmp;
                Messenger.ShowInfo(this, "После смены ТП, настоятельно рекомендуется произвести загрузку данных!", getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes            
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);    
    }
}
```

возникает исключение "android.view.inflateexception: Binary xml file line #9: Error inflating class com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference" Т.е. андройд не можен найти созданный мною класс.

Чтоя делаю не так? Почему андройд не видит созданный мною класс редактора настроек?

Полное сообщение об ошибке:

```
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1973)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4513)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:386)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1479)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at com.dialog.main.PreferenceTerminalActivity.onCreate(PreferenceTerminalActivity.java:27)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     ... 11 more
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:377)
06-22 10:58:47.580: E/AndroidRuntime(6317):     ... 22 more
```

Comment: `android.view.inflateexception: Binary xml file line #9: Error inflating class com.dialog.main.CustomEditTextPreference` - это всё, что пишет в stack trace?

Comment: полный стактрейс в студию!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ваш кастомный класс должен иметь 4 конструктора:

```
CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes);
CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr);
CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
CustomEditTextPreference(Context context);
```

А вы реализуете только 2 из них.

P.S. Именовать свой пакет `com.dialog.main` - не совсем кошерно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Причина действительно была в том, что я реализовал не все конструкторы.

Comment: @Barmaley, для того, чтобы класс инфлейтился, достаточно и одного конструктора: `CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);` (третий в вашем ответе). Автор вопроса как раз его и не реализовал.

Comment: Теперь буду знать.

Comment: @SuperCreeper - это смотря как задекларировать его в xml'ке :)

Comment: @Barmaley я вот всегда реализовывал только этот конструктор. Назовите, пожалуйста, случаи, при которых будут необходимы 1 и 2 конструкторы - очень интересно :)

Comment: @SuperCreeper [почитайте здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072153/creating-default-style-with-custom-attributes)